# Update method not saving

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple crud application using `Laravel 8`. My saving code is perfectly working. But my update code is not working. My console is not returning any error. Did I miss something that causes it not to save?.
**Code**

```
private $validations;

public function __constructor()
{
    $this->validations([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => "required|email",
        'phone' => "required",
        'dob' => "required|date",
        'interested_package' => 'sometimes'
    ]);
}
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $rules = $this->validations;
    $rules['id'] = 'required|exists:leads';
    $postData = $this->validate($request, $rules);
    Lead::where('id',  $postData['id'])->update($postData);
    return redirect()->route('lead.view', ['lead' =>  $postData['id']]);
}
```

> Update

Here is my Table structure [image]

Comment: alternate way **$postData->dob = $request->dob; $postData->save()**.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `Lead::where('id',  $postData['id'])->update($postData);` to this `Lead::where('id',  $postData['id'])->update($request->all());`

Comment: I tried it before I posted my problem. I got an error for a specific column. I updated my post

Comment: That`s because those column may not be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I think in constructor function you have to use $this->validations=[...]. Instead of $this->validations (...).

Comment: still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by changing the line `Lead::where('id',  $postData['id'])->update($postData);` into  `Lead::findOrFail($postData['id'])->update($request->all());`

I don't know the reason why it works that way.